# Calculated Value in Default value for Folder Name in SharePoint 2013

Tags: expression, sharepoint-2013, default-value, calculated-columns

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

I have a document library with folders inside it.

I want to add a column to the folders that holds the folder's name.

I added a column of type single line of text.

What do I need to write in the Default value part in the Calculated value text box?

All I need is that when I upload a file to this folder I will see the folder's name in the column.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this is not possible as calculated fields can only address the same item's properties.

I would strongly suggest to check out **Document Sets** in SharePoint. They actually are there for those needs because you can configure which columns your files will share with the document set (which is actually a folder). After configuration, you can add an item and that item will take over metadata from the parent (document set).

Hope this helps you